# The computer isn't completely turned-off when clicking "Shut Down" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Until recently I used Windows Vista on my computer. Now I have installed Windows 7. But when I choose shut-down in Windows, the computer isn't turned-off at 100%. The disks are turned off, but CPU-fan is still on and I can't use the "power-on"-button to start the computer, unless I hold it a few seconds to 100% turn off the computer before.

How to fix this?

Comment: Check what the event logs say - anything unusual there?

Comment: Are there any warning events?

Comment: If you boot the system using a Linux live CD, say Knoppix or Ubuntu, and shut down, does it shut off correctly?  If not, it is likely a hardware problem and its coinciding with the Win7 upgrade is a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using BitLocker, then there is a hotfix for this problem.

See this article:
[A computer stops responding during shutdown if BitLocker is enabled on the system drive on a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975496)

Another possibility from [Windows 7 Beta: Shutdown problem](http://www.jamespaulp.us/2009/01/25/windows-7-beta-shutdown-problem/)

> Device Manager, select "IEEE 1394 Bus
>   Host Controllers" group, only contains
>   one device called "VIA 1394 OHCI
>   Compilant Host COntroller" on that
>   click right mouse button and select
>   "Properties", select "Power
>   Management" tab, and finally check the
>   "Allow the computer to turn off this
>   device to save power" box.

In any case, even if you don't have such a device, better test that all possible devices have this power policy turned on.

Comment: I'm not using BitLocker, but I use dynamic disks and mirroring on the system drive, so maybe it's related!?

Comment: Questions: (1) Have you turned on "clear the virtual memory pagefile on shutdown", (2) Does it finally shut down after waiting at least 15 minutes, (3) What is your computer model?

Comment: @harrymc: (1) No, where do I find that setting? (2) No, it's all night.

Comment: Does this problem happen after boot into Safe mode?

Comment: I still have this problem. I have built the computer myself and the motherboard is a Asus P5KR.

Comment: OK: Have added another possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Check the system events logs (inside the computer management screen) from around the time when the system fails to shutdown.

Look for any errors or warnings around this time, because there is presumably something that is blocking the system from completely closing down and if there is a relevant log entry it will probably provide a good starting point for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you select shutdown and not standby? I think vista has standby where you would normally have shutdown in xp

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your HAL driver, or BIOS ACPI Settings.
I've encountered this problems on older version of windows, with Standard PC HAL instead of ACPI.

You need to check Device Manager ->  -> 
 should be: ACPI x86-based PC or Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) PC.

If you have anything else, then this is your problem.

Also, check your BIOS settings - there should be one that says: ACPI Enabled or something similar.

Comment: This only means you are on Windows 7 64-bit.