# PC not turning off

Tags: windows-7, power-supply, shutdown

I am trying to shut down my PC but it is not shutting down!

I am using windows 7. When I say shut down (from start menu), `windows is shutting down` screen comes up. After several seconds display goes off but all the fans in PC (power supply, GPU, CPU, inlet/outlet) and also the power LED, keep running. What might be the reason behind this? Is it a hardware issue or software/OS related issue?

I just re-installed my OS couple of hours back but issue still persists.

Update- When I say display goes off, It is not because of the power option or sleep mode. Display really goes off and doesn't come back on until I switch off the main switch and start it again.

Update- I booted system with Fedora 18 live usb, System didn't shut down even while using Fedora.

```
System Info - 

Processor- Intel core i5-3570k CPU @ 3.40GHz

OS- Microsoft Windows 7 ultimate 6.1.7601 Service pack 1

System Type - x64 based PC

BIOS version - American Megatrends INC. P1.70, 1/7/2013

SMBIOS -2.7

RAM - 4 GB.

Motherboard Build - ASRock Z77 Pro-4

GPU - Nvidia GTX 660
```

Comment: It could be a power setting in the BIOS

Comment: @bobSmith1432 How can I check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The computer isn't completely turned-off when clicking "Shut Down" in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/190649/the-computer-isnt-completely-turned-off-when-clicking-shut-down-in-windows-7)

Comment: @techie007 I am not using bitlocker, I read that question before posting, and it didn't help

Comment: Did you follow the advise on the other answers?  things like checking the event log, checked you ACPI setup, etc?  Please edit your question and include all you have tried already and what the results were.  PS: Try a LiveCD, if it can shut down properly, then you know it's a software issue related to your primary OS and/or its drivers/configuration.

Comment: @techie007 I checked the ACPI tab in BIOS but i am not sure what should be the settings

Comment: Can you provide your computer model? and other information pertaining to it. Ex. is it a laptop?

Comment: @Tech1337 Added system info

Comment: What updates have you applied recently?

Comment: @Ramhound updated GPU drivers

Comment: What is your BIOS version?

Comment: @Tech1337 American Megatrends INC. P1.70, 1/7/2013

Comment: @techie007 see the answer below, his advice nothing like solutions which are given on that other question. His solution worked for me.

Comment: Good to see!  It's amazing how much easier it is to accurately answer questions when the needed info is provided in the question eh? :)

Comment: @techie007 yeah i guess, looks like you have a lot of rep, can you move his answer to the other question as well?

Comment: Nope, I'm not a Moderator.  Perhaps "Flag" your question for mod attention, pick "Other", and suggest a merge with the other question. May not happen, but hey. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Disable Instant Boot and Other Settings

Disable Instant Boot by using the software that came with the motherboard on the CD. [Or Download it from the Manufacturer's Website (Direct Link; Win 7; x64; USA server)](http://www.asrock.com/downloadsite/utility/InstantBoot/InstantBoot%281.29%29.zip).

1. Execute the Instant Boot installation program under Windows.
2. Launch the Instant Boot program.
3. On Instant Boot main menu, choose the "Disable Instant Boot" option. Click "Apply".
4. Shutdown the computer and test to see if the problem is fixed.

If that doesn't work, also try removing/uninstalling these features if you installed them through the MB CD:

```
Intel Rapid Start driver ver:2.1.0.1002
Intel Smart Connect driver ver:2.0.1083.0
```

---

### Resetting the CMOS Settings

If disabling fast boot and the utilities I described in the previous section did not work, I would recommend clearing your CMOS settings by resetting the jumper cap on the motherboard.

> To clear and reset the
>   system parameters to default setup, please turn off the computer and unplug
>   the power cord from the power supply. After waiting for 15 seconds, use a
>   jumper cap to short pin2 and pin3 on CLRCMOS1 for 5 seconds. However,
>   please do not clear the CMOS right after you update the BIOS. If you need
>   to clear the CMOS when you just finish updating the BIOS, you must boot
>   up the system first, and then shut it down before you do the clear-CMOS action.
>   Please be noted that the password, date, time, user default profile, 1394
>   GUID and MAC address will be cleared only if the CMOS battery is removed.

[View this Manual](http://www.asrock.com/downloadsite/manual/Z77%20Pro4.pdf) for your motherboard to view pictures and more details. Page 31.

---

### Flashing the BIOS

If resetting the CMOS settings did not work and your BIOS version is below 1.80 (which it is), you can try flashing your BIOS. This option should be used as the last resort after you have tried everything possible. [Download the BIOS update from here](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z77%20Pro4/?cat=Download&os=BIOS). Place it on a USB and use the Instant Flash tool in the BIOS to proceed.

[Follow the guide in the manual](http://www.asrock.com/downloadsite/manual/Z77%20Pro4.pdf) on Page 52 for more details and information.

**Instant Flash**

> Instant Flash is a UEFI flash utility embedded in Flash ROM. This convenient
>   UEFI update tool allows you to update system UEFI without entering
>   operating systems first like MS-DOS or Windows®. Just save the new
>   UEFI file to your USB flash drive, floppy disk or hard drive and launch this
>   tool, then you can update your UEFI only in a few clicks without preparing
>   an additional floppy diskette or other complicated flash utility. Please
>   be noted that the USB flash drive or hard drive must use FAT32/16/12 file
>   system. If you execute Instant Flash utility, the utility will show the UEFI
>   files and their respective information. Select the proper UEFI file to update
>   your UEFI, and reboot your system after the UEFI update process is
>   completed.

Good luck and let me know the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, I'll get back to you as soon as I follow every step you mentioned.

Comment: Edited the post and added some more links.

Comment: Resetting CMOS worked for me, Thank you so much sir.

Comment: you sir deserve a bounty for this great answer!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked! Accept this as the answer so others with the same problem can know that this worked. Thanks.

Comment: I will accept it tomorrow, I want to assign bounty to you, for a good answer.

Comment: Motherboard was faulty. Had to replace it.